How to align columns on 2 table on top of each other
I am using overleaf
I have 2 tables, they have the same column names (content is different)
due to shorter text in the 2nd table the columns seems shifted.
is there a way i can align columns the same in both tables
here is a pic of how table aligned

here is my code
\begin{table}
\caption{Frequency of xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.}
\label{table_FreqDiag}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{lccc}
\toprule
            \textbf{Diagnosis}
                %&\thead{\shortstack{Clustering Time\\(Sec)}}
            &\textbf{\makecell{ICD-10\\Code}}
                &\textbf{\makecell{Total\\Cases}}
            &\textbf{\makecell{Primary\\Diagnosis Cases}} \\

\midrule
        
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx &xxx    &xxxxxx &x  \\          
            xxxxxx  xxxxx    xxxxx  &xxx    &xxxxx  &x  \\          
            xxx x xxxxxxxx  &xxx    &xxxx    &xx    \\          
            xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx &xxx    &xxxxx  &xx \\          
            xxxxxxx xxxxxx xx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx    &xxx &xxxxx    &xx  \\          
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{Top 5 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.}
\label{table_TopPrimDiag}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{lccc}
\toprule
            \textbf{Diagnosis}
                %&\thead{\shortstack{Clustering Time\\(Sec)}}
            &\textbf{\makecell{ICD-10\\Code}}
                &\textbf{\makecell{Total\\Cases}}
            &\textbf{\makecell{Primary\\Diagnosis Cases}} \\

\midrule
        
            xxxxxx  &xxx    &xxxx &xxxx \\          
            xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx  &xxx    &xxxx  &xxx \\          
            xxxxx xxxxxx xxxx  &xxx &xxxx    &xxxx  \\          
            xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx &xxx    &xxxxx  &xxxx   \\          
            xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxx    &xxx &xxxxx    &xxxx  \\          
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


Use a p{} column for the first column with the same width in both tables.  Everything else seems to use the same width in both.   BTW, you probably need to add \extracolsep for tabular*.

An easier solution is to use tabularx (tabularx package)and an X column.

The main problem with your tables is that their width exceeds \columnwidth by a considerable margin. This is happening because your code doesn't allow automatic line breaking of the material in some of the cells in the first column.
I would like to suggest that you switch from a tabular* to a tabularx setup and change the column type of the first column from l (which doesn't allow automatic line breaking) to a suitably modified form of X, both to allow automatic line-breaking and to suspend full justification in that column. (Full paragraph justification usually doesn't work well in narrow columns.) Applying some hanging indentation to the first column may also be a good idea. Finally, I would like to suggest not bold-facing the material in the header rows, in part in order to conserve scarce (horizontal) space.

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} % new
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight% suspend full justification
                    \hspace{0pt}%
                    \hangafter=1\hangindent=1ex}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Frequency of xx xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx.}
\label{table_FreqDiag}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} L ccc @{}}
\toprule
    Diagnosis
    &\makecell[t]{ICD-10\\Code}
    &\makecell[t]{Total\\Cases}
    &\makecell[t]{Primary\\Diagnosis\\Cases} \\
\midrule
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx &xxx &xxxxx &x  \\    
    xxxxxx  xxxxx xxxxx  &xxx &xxxxx  &x  \\    
    xxx x xxxxxxxx  &xxx &xxxx &xx \\    
    xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx &xxx &xxxxx  &xx \\    
    xxxxxxx xxxxxx xx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx &xxx &xxxxx &xx  \\    
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip\bigskip

\caption{Top 5 xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxx.}
\label{table_TopPrimDiag}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} L ccc @{}}
\toprule
    Diagnosis
    &\makecell[t]{ICD-10\\Code}
    &\makecell[t]{Total\\Cases}
    &\makecell[t]{Primary\\Diagnosis\\Cases} \\
\midrule
    xxxxxx  &xxx &xxxx &xxxx \\    
    xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx  &xxx &xxxx  &xxx \\    
    xxxxx xxxxxx xxxx  &xxx &xxxx &xxxx  \\    
    xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx &xxx &xxxxx  &xxxx   \\    
    xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxx &xxx &xxxxx &xxxx  \\    
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}


What about this solution (you have to change the width of the columns to your taste or needings):
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{70mm}|p{30mm}|p{20mm}|p{20mm}|}
        \hline 
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Some text} \\ \hline
         Diagnosis & ICD-10 Code & Total Cases & Primary Diagnosis Cases \\ \hline
         M short & 43 & 7 & 123 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{70mm}|p{30mm}|p{20mm}|p{20mm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Some text} \\ \hline
         Diagnosis & ICD-10 Code & Total Cases & Primary Diagnosis Cases \\ \hline
         M longer longer and even much longer & 11 & 39 & 56\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

